# Python Dictionary, finding a key with multiple values using a value?

Tags: python, dictionary

How would you go about using a value to display the key.
Lets say it goes like this:
dict = {'number1':[1,2,3,4,5], 'number2':[6,7,8,9,10]}
Using one of the values, how would I be able to print the key?

Comment: Please show us what you have written.

Comment: Dictionaries are made for key -> value lookups. If you need to do the lookup the other way around you should consider restructuring your data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that there *is* such a key, you can use generator comprehension:

```py
dct = {'number1':[1,2,3,4,5], 'number2':[6,7,8,9,10]}

x = 9
output = next((k for k, v in dct.items() if x in v))
print(output) # number2
```

If you are going to do this procedure a lot of times repeatedly, then it might be better to once make a dictionary that maps a number to its corresponding key, and then use it repeatedly.

```py
dct_inverse = {x: k for k, lst in dct.items() for x in lst}
print(dct_inverse[x]) # number2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
key_lst = list(my_dict.keys())
val_lst = list(my_dict.values())

position = val_lst.index("some value")
print(key_lst[position])
```